# Github actions run a workflow right after another and only when changes detected in folder

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have the `migrate.yaml` workflow which I want it to be triggered only when one of the previous workflows ("Deploy to Staging", "Deploy to Production") were completed **and** only if changes were detected in the `app/migrations` folder. When one of the previous worfklows complete it skips the `paths` check and triggers the `migrate` workflow although no changes occurred in the `app/migrations` folder.

This is the workflow file:

```
name: Migrate

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Deploy to Staging", "Deploy to Production"]
    types:
      - completed
    paths:
      - 'app/migrations'
```

Any ideas?

Thanks